# How to call a bootstrap modal inside ng-grid cellRenderer?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular6

I'm a newbie for Angular6. I'm woking with [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) and [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io).

I have a cell containing a button rendered by using [cellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/). I'd like that button to call a function for opening bootstrap modal. I can't figure out how to call bootstrap modal inside cellRenderer.

myApp.component.ts

```js
export class MyAppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}
  
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'name', field:'name'},
    {headerName: 'edit', cellRenderer: this.editCellRenderer}
  ];
  
  rowData = [
    {name:'foo', edit:''},
    {name:'bar', edit:''}
  ];
  
  ngOnInit(){}
  
  editCellRenderer(params){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<button class="btnEdit">edit</button>';
    var btnEdit = div.querySelectorAll('.btnEdit')[0];
    
    btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function(){
      //Have no idea how to call bootstrap modal successfully :(
    });
    
    return div;
  }
  
  open(content){
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
  
}
```

myApp.component.html

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
      
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

I'm really stuck and really need help. Thanks everyone to spend your time for my problem.

Comment: Just pass the `open` function inside btnEdit.addEventListner` check again??

Comment: If I call functions outside the cellRenderer. I will throw an error 'ERROR TypeError: this.open is not a function'. @Sanoj_V

Comment: see if you put only `this.modalService.open(content);` is giving same error ??

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined @Sanoj_V

It seems like I can't call any function outside cellRenderer.

Comment: Ok. Do you need is like modal popup open when edit button is click for same data, am i right??

Comment: @Sanoj_V Yes, you are. But I initially want open a empty modal. After that I will work on data.

Comment: Have you checked this link: (https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-dynamic/) this link gives you an idea further how to call function. If not useful for you then produce a stackblitz I will check further

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I think it's because "this" is undefined when your method is called (try doing a `console.log(this)` in your `editCellRenderer` method). I overcame this problem by telling my renderer the context (i.e., `this`) in which it is running, but I'm not sure that this is the "correct" approach. I'm using the `cellRendererFramework` property in the column definition, which I believe is the recommended approach for Angular. Here's my column definition for my column:

```
{
  cellRendererFramework: GridCellActionsComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    parent: this
  }
}
```

My `GridCellActionsComponent` class contains the following:

```
export interface IGridCellActionPars {
parent: IGridCellActions
}
export class GridCellActionsComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
private gridCellActionPars: IGridCellActionPars;
agInit(cellRendererParams: ICellRendererParams): void {
  this.gridCellActionsPars = cellRendererParams['gridCellActionsPars'];
}
private editButtonClick(): void {
  this.gridCellActionsPars.parent.editButtonClick();
}
```